# How can i get field value in Xamarin Android firestore

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.android

how can I get current User Full Name?
This is Email from firebaseAuth.

```
AccountEmailText.Text = "Email: "+ FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Email;
```

[Firestore Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtIuI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I did a test with the latest version of nuget `Xamarin.Firebase.Auth`,and  we could get the `DisplayName` of `CurrentUser`, and nuget `Xamarin.Firebase.Auth` exposes only one interface about the user name:

```
string DisplayName =   FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.DisplayName;
```

For more, check [Access user information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start#access_user_information).

Comment: Thank you brother I was already test but It's not work.Do you know how to read firestore  field value in document and display to Textview?

Comment: `Do you know how to read firestore field value in document and display to Textview?` Sorry for the late response. For this,you can get the string value and set the Text for TextView(`textview.Text = DisplayName; `).